# Error in loading DLL only when I'm in debug (vb6)

Tags: windows, dll, vb6, 64-bit, w3wp

I have a very big problem, when I debug a VB6 "stack" i got "Error in loading dll". I see nothing in ProcMon except w3wp.exe searching weird registry keys like :  HKCU\Software\Classes.VBP or HKCU\Software\Classes\VisualBasic.Project\CLSID I found nothing on my current problem. If I start all the stack in debug, everthing work fine.

Example:

If I want to debug dll #2

w3wp.exe => DLL #1 vb6 (in debug) => DLL #2 vb6 (in debug)
everything works good but... if i want to debug like :

w3wp.exe => DLL #1 (NOT in debug) => DLL #2 vb6 (in debug) BAM! it throw "Error in loading DLL"

I have added full acces in dcom and put my user in all app pools. I guess it's somewhere "windows memory protection" or bug with dllhost debugger?

For your interest, i'm on Windows 8.1 64Bit

If you have any ideas, I take all!

Comment: it is very dangerous to debug a program in VB6. The IDE loads the libraryes into its address space, it can end in a crash the development environment and the loss of Your data. Can you show your code?

Comment: I can't expose the source code, but I found a work around, I need to put the com application running as "Server" not library... if not w3wp try to open .vbp files without entering in debug... How can I tell to w3wp to attach debug with vb6.exe process ?